# Insert character by its Unicode name

Tags: interactive, unicode, characters, insert-char

From the documentation of `insert-char`, I cannot see why

```el
(insert-char "GREEK SMALL LETTER EPSILON")
```

doesn't work.  Is there a non-interactive way to insert a character
given its Unicode name?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> From the documentation of `insert-char`, I cannot see why
>
> `(insert-char "GREEK SMALL LETTER EPSILON")`
>
> doesn't work.

It doesn't work because `insert-char` understands Unicode character names only when called interactively (e.g. via <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd> or <kbd>M-x</kbd>`insert-char`<kbd>RET</kbd>), as stated in its docstring:

```
Interactively, prompt for CHARACTER.  You can specify CHARACTER in one
of these ways:

 - As its Unicode character name, e.g. "LATIN SMALL LETTER A".
   Completion is available; if you type a substring of the name
   preceded by an asterisk ‘*’, Emacs shows all names which include
   that substring, not necessarily at the beginning of the name.

 - As a hexadecimal code point, e.g. 263A.  Note that code points in
   Emacs are equivalent to Unicode up to 10FFFF (which is the limit of
   the Unicode code space).

 - As a code point with a radix specified with #, e.g. #o21430
   (octal), #x2318 (hex), or #10r8984 (decimal).
```

The [`interactive` spec](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Commands.html) of `insert-char` delegates to `read-char-by-name` for Unicode name completion and translation to the corresponding [character code](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Character-Type.html).

When `insert-char` is called from Lisp, its first argument `CHARACTER` should satisfy the predicate [`characterp`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Character-Codes.html).

> Is there a non-interactive way to insert a character given its Unicode name?

There are multiple ways; here's one for Emacs 26 and subsequent versions:

```el
(insert (char-from-name "GREEK SMALL LETTER EPSILON"))
```

Here's another for earlier Emacs versions:

```el
(insert (cdr (assoc "GREEK SMALL LETTER EPSILON" (ucs-names))))
```

Comment: Where is `char-from-name` defined?

Comment: @JeanPierre `M-x find-function RET char-from-name RET`, which reminds me that `char-from-name` was just added in Emacs 26; I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: I can get your "char-from-name" example to work, but the last example using "ucs-names" just gives me an wrong type argument error.

Comment: @A.Ellett What's your `M-x emacs-version RET`? As stated in the answer, the very last example stopped working in Emacs 26 and subsequent versions.

Comment: I misunderstood what you meant.  I thought you'd meant that the old code would still work and that `char-from-name` only came into being after Emacs 26.  I have Emacs 27.2.  So you've now explained why the old approach didn't work.  Thank you.